# Is standard output of a process flushed if the process crashes?

Tags: c#, .net, process, io, io-redirection

I'm starting a Python process using the C# `Process` class. The standard output is redirected as I want to capture it. I'm able to get the standard output properly except when it *crashes*. We are aware that it will crash. **We need to inspect the standard output when it crashes**. We are not getting exact stdout once crashed.

When I run that script in the console manually, I can see the exact output at the time of the crash, but when I redirect the stdout using the `>` operator, the output is not written to the file, if the process crashed. I suspect that the I/O buffers are not getting flushed, if the process crashes. Is this true? Thanks in advance.

```
var lastLineOfStdOut = null;
var p = new Process
    {
        StartInfo =
        {
            FileName = ... ,
            Arguments = ... ,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        }
    };


p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Data == null) return;
        lastLineOfStdOut = e.Data;
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
    };

p.Start();
p.BeginOutputReadLine();
p.WaitForExit();

var exitCode = p.ExitCode; // Use this to figure out if it crashed
```

Comment: Is it possible the output is going to stderr instead? Check `p.ErrorDataReceived`?